# Swift image appear animation from bottom of its frame to top (wipe animation)

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I just want to get some ideas on how to approach the situation I have in hand.

I have created some images which I want to animate, but the animation I want is not default given, so its giving me some hard time.

The animation I want is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byGMC.gif  (not from bottom of the screen, from the bottom of images' own frame)

When a button is pressed I want the button/image start appear from bottom of its frame to the top, like the **wipe** animation in powerpoint :)
So naturaly it will default as hidden and when a button is pressed it will animate in.

I did try a few methods but non of them is actually doing the job I want.

Like this one:

```
extension UIView{
    
func animShow(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 5, options: [.transitionFlipFromBottom],
                       animations: {
                        
                        self.center.y -= self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        self.isHidden = false
    }
    func animHide(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear],
                       animations: {
                        self.center.y += self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        },  completion: {(_ completed: Bool) -> Void in
        self.isHidden = true
            })
    }
}
```

so it slides in the image but this is not what I want, you may try the code, just add this and write `image.animShow()` in viewDidLoad, button is the button which I want to animate.

I appreciate every bit of help, and I am a newbie in swift programming
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the image to "slide up and fade in"? Or, do you want the image to "fade up from its bottom"?

Comment: @DonMag  I want the image to fade up from its bottom, so the image will be hidden at first then with the animation, from the images bottom it will start to appear till the whole image is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do a "soft wipe" animation... here is one.

We can add a gradient layer mask and then animate the gradient.

When using a layer mask, clear (alpha 0) areas *hide* what's under the mask, and opaque (alpha 1) areas *show* what's under the mask. This includes parts of the mask that are translucent - alpha 0.5 for example - so the content becomes "translucent".

To get a "soft wipe" we want the gradient to use only a portion of the frame, so if we set the starting Y point to 0.5 (halfway down), for example, we can set the ending Y point to 0.6 ... this would give us a horizontal "gradient band".

So, a yellow-to-red gradient at 0.5 to 0.6 would look like this:

[image]

If we set the starting Y to 1.0 and the ending Y to 1.1, the gradient band will start "off the bottom of the view" ... and we can animate it up until it's "off the top of the view" (note that converted to gif loses some of the smooth gradient property):

[image]

Now, if we instead use clear-to-red and set it as a layer **mask**, using the same animation it will "soft wipe" the view, it will look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Can't get the animated gif small enough to post here, so here's a link to the animation: https://i.imgur.com/jo2DH3Z.mp4

Here's some sample code for you to play with. Lots of comments in there:

```
class AnimatedGradientImageView: UIImageView {
    
    let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // vertical gradient
        //  start at bottom
        maskLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        
        //  to bottom + 1/10th
        maskLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.1)

        // use "if true" to see the layer itself
        // use "if false" to see the image reveal
        if false {
            // yellow to red
            maskLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
            // add it as a sublayer
            layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)
        } else {
            // clear to red
            maskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
            // set the mask
            layer.mask = maskLayer
        }
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // set mask layer frame
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    func reveal() -> Void {
        
        let anim1: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "startPoint.y")

        // anim1 animates the gradient start point Y
        //  to -0.1 (1/10th above the top of the view)
        anim1.toValue = -0.1
        anim1.duration = 1.0
        anim1.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        anim1.fillMode = .forwards
        
        let anim2: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "endPoint.y")

        // anim2 animates the gradient end point Y
        //  to 0.0 (the top of the view)
        anim2.toValue = 0.0
        anim2.duration = 1.0
        anim2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        anim2.fillMode = .forwards

        maskLayer.add(anim1, forKey: nil)
        maskLayer.add(anim2, forKey: nil)

    }

}

class AnimatedGradientViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testImageView = AnimatedGradientImageView(frame: .zero)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // replace with your image name
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "sampleImage") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!")
        }
        // set the image
        testImageView.image = img
        
        testImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testImageView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // size: 240 x 240
            testImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            testImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            // centered
            testImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // tap anywhere in the view
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        testImageView.reveal()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: sorry for delayed response. I appreciate your detailed answer I understood the purpose and use of mask, and its what I wanted I have executed it and works like a charm but I need to study it more so I understand the whole work prenciple of it, I would love to ask you questions about it more in the days to come. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to give the **height constraint** of the image from the storyboard and **set the height to 0**
and take the image height constraint into your file like below

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Here is the animation code.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2, options: [.transitionFlipFromBottom],
                       animations: {
                        self.image.frame = CGRect(x: self.image.frame.origin.x, y: self.image.frame.origin.y - 100, width: self.image.frame.size.width, height: 100)
                        self.imageHeight.constant = 100
                        self.image.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
```

[Click here to see animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU0be.gif)

Comment: I have tried your code and actualy its more like a scale animation, not an actual wipe animation. As I increase the height constant the image gets bigger. But i appreciate it very much because I did need this for another job i have in hand :)